# Length of variable with ${#VAR} comments out my code

Tags: xcode, bash

I am trying to write a Bash script in Xcode where I need to use the number of characters in a variable to index another variable.

Using `index=${#variable}` is problematic because `#` creates a comment block halfway through the line of code.

Does anyone have a) recommendations on changing my Xcode preferences to alter the behaviour of `#` or b) another way of storing the length of `variable` in `index`?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Xcode. I had same problems with `vim`. All I could understand is when the shebang is  for `sh`, it won't consider it whereas if you use shebang for `bash` it would get ok. I don't remember exactly but I guess that syntax is not allowed in `sh`. I am not sure though, I faced this almost 4-5 months ago.

Comment: It is allowed in [sh](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) too.  I would regard this as bug in the syntax highlighter of Xcode. Maybe it would make sense to report it to Apple.

Comment: Can you use `index=$(awk '{print length}' <<< "$variable")` or `index=$(wc -c <<< "$variable")`?

Comment: @Mihir I just tried a sample script with with the commented out line implicated in `index`. It still worked (my shebang is `#!/bin/bash`). Also, @stephanmg, I tried your first option and this works as well. Appreciate the help everyone. @user1934428 I will report it.